# how to correct font error of mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

hello i am using MYSQL for my data base. When i use Mongolian font. it saves in MYSQL like ????. How to correct this?
[image: this is my data base picture]

When i save in English it looks ok but in Mongolian it looks like ??? in the picture. 
In the screen it also looks like ????

my MYSQL insert code is:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO core_network (system_name,sub_cat,location,alarmtype,severity,start_time,end_time,reason,shift_operation)
    VALUES ('$S_name','$subcategory','$city','$a_type','$severity','$S_time','$F_time','$reason','$shift_operation')";
```

how to correct?

Comment: What is `$severity` & `$a_type`?

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 for your data format and your page encoding?

Comment: this is just variable. behind of this there mongolian words like Улаанбаатар, Улаан-Уул, ect.

Comment: this words saved like ????????. In mysql

Comment: Have you tried to replace the mongolian charaters with English one's to see if it appears as normal? if so, then the problem is somewhere with the Unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [collation of the columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-table.html) to an UTF-8 one like `utf8_general_ci`.

Also you have to make sure that the [connection charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html) is UTF-8 as well, for example by issuing

```
SET NAMES "utf8"
```

before any other SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host1, $user, $pass)
or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database1,$connection)
or die("Error in selecting the database:".mysql_error());
```

after connect to DB and before use "SELECT" use this code :

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8",$connection);
```

Comment: Helli where should i use this?

Comment: after connect to database and before any action use this code: mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8",$connection);